# Django inineformset save and delete

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to do something really simple.  But, there is a problem I cannot figure out, so I appreciate any help.  Here is my code:

```
 # in views.py
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        assembly_id = kwargs.get('assembly_id', None)
        active_assembly_project = assembly_instance = Assembly.objects.get(id = assembly_id)

        # Second, if the specified assembly does not belong to the active development project, then
        PartTypeInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Assembly, PartType,
                                                             formset = BasePartTypeInlineFormSet,
                                                             fields = __all__
                                                             can_delete = True
                                                            )

        kwargs = {'assembly_project': active_assembly_project, }

        part_type_formset = PartTypeInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = assembly_instance)

        if part_type_formset.is_valid():
            part_types_cd = part_type_formset.cleaned_data
            forms_marked_for_deletion = part_type_formset.deleted_forms   # <== Correctly identifies the forms marked for deletion 

            part_type_formset_kwargs = {'assembly_project': active_assembly_project,}
            assembly_development_types = part_type_formset.save(**part_type_formset_kwargs)   


# forms.py
class BaseDevelopmentTypeInlineFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):


    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):

        forms = self.forms

        if any(self.errors):
            errors = self.errors
            return

        for form in self.forms:
            should_delete_form = form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE', False)
            print ('should_delete_form: ', should_delete_form)   # <= Correctly shows the forms that have 'DELETE': on

            if self.can_delete and should_delete_form:
                continue


    def save(self, commit = True, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' Custom save to save the development projects when saving development types'''

        the_assembly_project = kwargs.pop('assembly_project', None)

        instances = super(BasePartTypeInlineFormSet, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)

        assert False   #<== gives me instances = []  !!!

        for instance in instances:

            if commit:
                instance.save()

            else:
                instance.assembly_project = the_assembly_project
                if obj in instances.deleted_objects:
                    obj.delete()

                the_instance = instance.save()

        return instances
```

The problem is two-fold:
1) The save method is not working properly.  While the cleaned data shows all the sample forms to be valid, none of the forms show up in the save method.  This is marked in the above code.
2) The [documentation] (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#can-delete) says:

> "On the other hand, if you are using a plain FormSet, it’s up to you to handle formset.deleted_forms, perhaps in your formset’s save() method, as there’s no general notion of what it means to delete a form."

Given that my forms are not showing up in the save method, obviously I am not able to verify if the forms to be deleted are in fact deleted or not.  However, given that I am using inlineformset rather than formset, I'd appreciate if you can confirm the same works for inlineformset as it does for formset or not.

Comment: I don't understand the line `assert False` this will always fail.

Comment: assert False is for debugging purposes and is there to show that the forms do not show up in the save method

Comment: note that `instances` will never contain the objects that need to be deleted.

Comment: in a model formset, if you save with `commit=True`, the instances that need to be deleted are in fact deleted. If you save with `commit=False`, they won't be deleted, but they are also not returned by the save method. In that case you would need to loop through `self.deleted_objects` and delete obj yourself.